# how to start/stop weblogic set of managed servers from a given list using wlst

Tags: weblogic12c, wlst

First I will create a list of servers which are up and running and write them to a text file after that I want bring down all the servers in list at once and then restart all the servers at once

Answer (score -1):

```
 ## connect the Admin server first    
 connect('<username>','<PASSWD>','t3://ip:port')

 ## if applications are running u can use this 
stopApplication('<appname>')
stopApplication('<appname>')
stopApplication('<n....>')

 ## if you want to delete the applications u please follow below thing
edit()
startEdit()
undeploy('<appname>',timeout=60000)
undeploy('<n...>',timeout=60000)
save()
activate()


shutdown('<manageservername>','Server')
shutdown('<managesername'>,'Server)'
shutdown('<n....>','Server')
shutdown('<AdminServer>','Server')
disconnect()
exit()

####for servers starting follow reverse order.

connect('<username>','<PASSWD>','t3://ip:port')
start('<manageservername>'); 
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
```